# jquery get children of children of children

Tags: jquery

Okay, this may be a bit basic. The HTML is :

```
<div class="parents-of-all">
<p>
    <a>
        <span class="thechild">Something</span>
    </a>
</p>
```

The jquery is

```
$('.parents-of-all').click(function(){
    alert($(this).find('span').attr('class'));
});
```

But somehow it doesn't work. Test it here :

http://jsfiddle.net/3zn7e/1/

My question is how can I traverse to the span? My usual way is

```
$(this).children().children().children().attr('class');
```

I'm sure there are shorter ways than this and using find() is one of them, but I can't seem to make it work.

Many thanks!

EDIT : DUH! Apparently I forgot the . for the parents-of-all DOM selector. Sometimes the simplest error is right there in your face.

But again, is there any difference between using find() and multiple children() ?  I find using multiple children() ensures more accurate traversing since we can add elements selector if we want, but any other major difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were missing the dot in your class selector:

```
$('.parents-of-all').click(function(){
    alert($(this).find('span').attr('class'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/3zn7e/2

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to change an attribute on the children-with-ancestor or children-with-parent, you should use the respective selector:

- [decendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)
- [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

For example:

```
$('.parents-of-all span').addClass('hello');
```

Would apply the class "hello" to all `<span>` elements that are descendants of an element of class `parents-of-all`.